# Animating a Div with Responsiveness

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, responsive

Just need a little help. I want to animate below box to be responsive to the size of the page using (window).width(); and (window).height();
Where should i implement the (window).width & height function? Here is what I have done so far:

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".box").click(function(){

                run();

            });
        });

        function run(){
            var duration=1000;
            var width=$(window).width();
            var height=$(window).height();
            $(".box").animate({"marginLeft":"1000px"},duration,function(){
                $(this).animate({"marginTop":"600px"},duration,function(){
                    $(this).animate({"marginLeft":"0px"},duration,function(){
                        $(this).animate({"marginTop":"0px"},duration,function(){
                            run();


                        });
                    });   
                });
            });

        }
```

CSS:

```
.box{border:1px solid black; width:200px; height:200px; float:left;}
```

Comment: apply `transition:all 0.8s ease;` effect on your css

Comment: @prasad No need because he is using animate from jquery

Comment: i'm looking for the div to move based on the size of the page, so if i minimize the page to say 600px width and 200 height, then it will animate to those dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use your window width and height, the tack out the height and width of the box like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".box").click(function() {

    run();

  });
});

function run() {
  var duration = 1000;
  var width = $(window).width();
  var height = $(window).height();
  $(".box").animate({
    "marginLeft": width - 200 //<-----
  }, duration, function() {
    $(this).animate({
      "marginTop": height - 200 //<-----
    }, duration, function() {
      $(this).animate({
        "marginLeft": "0px"
      }, duration, function() {
        $(this).animate({
          "marginTop": "0px"
        }, duration, function() {
          run();


        });
      });
    });
  });

}
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Comment: So the width worked in response to page size though the box was sticking out of the page a little bit, but the height did not? EDIT: firefox doesn't work with .height(); for some reason, chrome worked though, still the box has about 10px of itself outside of the current page size

Comment: You can just adjust the number that are subtracted from the width so it does not sick out. Then when you resize the window it will tak one iteration of the animation for the width and height to adjust. You can solv it by checking for $(windows).resize().

Comment: okay i just adjusted to "-210" and it animated perfectly. Thank you for your help!